# Open a file with a flexible name from user input in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to ask how can I open a file to write in Prolog with the name of the file should get from users. For example:

```
open('name_of_file_number.txt',write,..).
```

In this case, number is a value get from user input. Thanks very much.

Comment: `Number = 27, number_chars(Number, NChs), append("name_of_file",NChs, Chs), atom_chars(File, Chs), open(File, write, Stream), ...`  with `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars)`

Comment: Thanks false. I tried to do as number_chars(), append, and string_to_list and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SWI-Prolog, you can use

```
Number=27, atomics_to_string([name_of_file,Number], File), open(File, write, ...)
```

as an alternative to the standard solution given by user *false*.